# How do you set controller scope from the result of a signalr request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, signalr

I have a simple signalr hub created which is started within an angularjs service which is called hubService. I am able to inject the hubService into my controller successfully. However, when I call the hub method it returns some data correctly. I am not able to set the $scope within the controller from the signalr method callback.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
// The application.
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.service("hubService", function () {
    this.notification = $.connection.notificationHub;
    $.connection.hub.start();
});

// A controller manages some part of the application.
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope,hubService) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.messageOutput = "";

    hubService.notification.client.addNewMessageToPage = function(message) {
        this.messageOutput = message; // this fails.
    }

    $scope.doSomething = function () {
        hubService.notification.server.send($scope.message);
    }
});
```

The UI code is simple as well and is as follows:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
        <button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</button>
        {{ messageOutput }}
    </div>
```

What is the best way to get the update the scope correctly from within the signalr callback?

If I change to the following code for the signalr callback I can get some results.

```
    hubService.notification.client.addNewMessageToPage = function(message) {
        this.messageOutput = message; // this works but
        this.$apply();                // if I don't have this it is still broken.
    }.bind($scope);
    ...
```

This is not ideal because it seems somewhat of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$apply()` is not a hack.

When updating scope from events or code outside of angular context it is necessary to tell angular about it in order to run digests to update the view.

It may be better to use `$timeout` (which calls `$apply()` internally) so as not to run into conflicts where a digest is already in progress. This pushes the call to end of any active digest cycle